# Popover close when click on its body,How to disable?

Tags: angularjs

Popover content always close when click to focus cursor on Popover body

here my popover directive

```
 angular.module('collect').directive('popover', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        replace : true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var popover = null;
            // define popover for this element
            $timeout(function() {
                // TODO: maybe can continue using $(element) or just element instead of saving popover var
                popover = $(element).popover({
                    html: true,
                    placement: scope.placement || "top",
                    // grab popover content from the next element
                    content: $(element).siblings(".pop-content").contents(),
                });
                popover.on('show.bs.popover', function($event) {
                    //hide any visible popover
                    $('.popover').not($(element)).popover('hide');
                });
            },0 , false);

            var unbinder = scope.$on(
                "$destroy",
                function handleDestroyEvent() {
                    if (popover) {
                        popover.off('show.bs.popover');
                        popover = null;
                    }
                    $(element).off('.popover.data-api'); // TODO: I think this is only for jquery, not bootstrap
                    $(element).popover('destroy');
                    element.remove();
                    unbinder();
                }
            );

            $("body").on("click touchstart", '.popover', function() {
                $(this).popover("show");
                $('.popover').not(this).popover("hide"); // hide other popovers
                return false;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and this one is how I use popover

```
<span>
<popover class="tbl-act-btn action-column action-column-ic popover-btn" title="Comments">
    <span title="{{columnName}}">
        <i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-comments-o' : !isComment(commentContentTemp), 'fa-comments' : isComment(commentContentTemp)}"></i>
    </span>
</popover>
<div ng-hide="true" class="pop-content">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="popover-textarea form-control" name="comment" ng-model="commentContentTemp"></textarea>
        <div class="popover-footer">
           <button type="button"
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok btn btn-primary popover-submit" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="updateComment($event)"></button>
           <button type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove btn btn-default popover-cancel" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="cancelUpdateComment($event)"></button> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It always close Popover when I click on textArea to edit text. I want it close whenever click on update, cancel, or outside Popover.

Comment: i think your code are too much Jquery style. you can use angular boostrap popover or angular ngDialog too

Comment: This code I inherit from my team member and other project. not my own, I try to fix that problem , but can not